# How to show only one piece of data in one column with multiple rows listed in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have these two MySQL tables:

Polls table, with an ID and a title...

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | title                                                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
```

and a poll_data table, with the options...

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------+
| ID | pollID | text                    | votes |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------+
|  1 |      1 | No accedo               |    11 |
|  2 |      1 | Una vez al mes          |    10 |
|  3 |      1 | Una vez a la semana     |    23 |
|  4 |      1 | Una vez al día          |    20 |
|  5 |      1 | Más de una vez al día   |    19 |
|  6 |      2 | Coche particular        |    10 |
|  7 |      2 | Autobus                 |    20 |
|  8 |      2 | Tranvía                 |    50 |
|  9 |      2 | Bicicleta               |     5 |
| 10 |      2 | Taxi                    |     5 |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------+
```

I want to get this result, showing only one piece of data in one column with multiple rows listed in another column:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| ID | title                                                | text                    | votes |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | No accedo               |    11 |
|    |                                                      | Una vez al mes          |    10 |
|    |                                                      | Una vez a la semana     |    23 |
|    |                                                      | Una vez al día          |    20 |
|    |                                                      | Más de una vez al día   |    19 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Coche particular        |    10 |
|    |                                                      | Autobus                 |    20 |
|    |                                                      | Tranvía                 |    50 |
|    |                                                      | Bicicleta               |     5 |
|    |                                                      | Taxi                    |     5 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Executing this SQL command:

```
SELECT polls.ID, polls.title, poll_data.text, poll_data.votes
FROM polls
INNER JOIN poll_data
ON polls.ID = poll_data.pollID;
```

I get this result:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
| ID | title                                                | text                    | votes |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | No accedo               |    11 |
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | Una vez al mes          |    10 |
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | Una vez a la semana     |    23 |
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | Una vez al día          |    20 |
|  1 | ¿Con qué frecuencia accedes a Moodle?                | Más de una vez al día   |    19 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Coche particular        |    10 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Autobus                 |    20 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Tranvía                 |    50 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Bicicleta               |     5 |
|  2 | ¿Qué medio de transporte usas más frecuentemente?    | Taxi                    |     5 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: What has that got to do with a right join?  You're using an inner join.  Maybe the terminology is confusing you?  Or you mean to be using a right join?

Comment: I really don't know which one is the best to get the desired results, sorry.

Comment: The result you want you can only have with some variable tricks and `if` or `case` statements. It is not about right or inner. Inner join is just fine. Or programatically

Comment: Right join is the wrong term here...am I right with saying you are simply trying to return the title only once, while the query you have lists it again on each row?  This is normally something reserved for whatever tool you are using to display your information to your users, not SQL itself.

Comment: It can be done with sql on mysql. But you are absolutelly right @Twelfth

Comment: First of all thanks to all. Yes I'm trying to show the ID and title fields once. I really don't know if it is possible with - a not too complicated SQL sentence -.

Comment: Maybe use GROUP_CONCAT,it will add them up in a comma delimited string.

Comment: It's a matter of **presenting your data** with client code not retrieving the data. Just do it in your client code. Your query is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone said on the comments this is a matter of show your data. But if you really want to do this on pure MySql, as I said, it is possible. Here is what you need (maybe it can be improved, but I'm too tired to think now)

```
SELECT IF(ord=(cnt-1),id,'') id, 
       IF(ord=(cnt-1),title,'') title,
       text,
       votes
FROM
(
SELECT polls.ID, 
       polls.title, 
       poll_data.text, 
       poll_data.votes, 
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(@remain,0) = 0
            THEN @remain:=grouped.cnt-1
            ELSE @remain:=@remain-1 
        END as ord,
       grouped.cnt
  FROM polls INNER JOIN poll_data
           ON (polls.ID = poll_data.pollID)
     INNER JOIN 
          (select pollid, 
                  count(*) cnt 
             FROM poll_data 
             GROUP BY pollid) grouped
        ON grouped.pollid = polls.ID
ORDER BY polls.id, ord desc) a
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c7c3/18